# How to submit the values of checkbox?

Tags: php, html

On my form I have this part :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="city" value="Nicosia" class="choosecity">Nicosia<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="city" value="Limassol" class="choosecity">Limassol<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="city" value="Larnaca" class="choosecity">Larnaca<br>
```

and on the results page where I use the mail function, I want to get thechecked cities.

I used this without result:

```
foreach($_POST['city'] as $checkbox){
    echo $checkbox . ' ';
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your form names need to utlize the array syntax then, using `<input name="city[]">`

Answer (score 2):

Use `name="city[]"`.  Otherwise you will only be able to submit one city.  You may also want to use

```
$cities = isset($_POST['city']) ? $_POST['city'] : array();
foreach ($cities as $city)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to name your inputs as an array `name="city[]"`

Answer (score 1):

PHP uses the square bracket syntax to convert form inputs into an array, so when you use name="education[]" you will get an array when you do this:

```
$educationValues = $_POST['education']; // Returns an array
print_r($educationValues); // Shows you all the values in the array
```

So for example:

```
<p><label>Please enter your most recent education<br>
    <input type="text" name="education[]"></p>
<p><label>Please enter any previous education<br>
    <input type="text" name="education[]"></p>
<p><label>Please enter any previous education<br>
    <input type="text" name="education[]"></p>
```

Will give you all entered values inside of the $_POST['education'] array.

In JavaScript, it is more efficient to get the element by id...

```
document.getElementById("education1");
```

The id doesn't have to match the name:

```
<p><label>Please enter your most recent education<br>
    <input type="text" name="education[]" id="education1"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just just have to add this `[]` to input name this will create an array starting with `[0]`. The result will look so:

```
array(
   [0] => 'Nicosia',
   [1] => 'Limassol',
   [2] => 'Larnaca',
)
```

**The HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="city[]" value="Nicosia" class="choosecity" />Nicosia<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="city[]" value="Limassol" class="choosecity" />Limassol<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="city[]" value="Larnaca" class="choosecity" />Larnaca<br>
```

**The PHP:**

```
if( isset($_POST[city]) && is_array($_POST[city]) ){
   foreach($_POST[city] as $checkbox){
       echo $checkbox . ' ';
   }
}
```